# copy a value and paste the same until it reaches a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy the value present in the B1 to B20 and paste until B40000

I tried

```
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Range("A2").Select
 Selection.End(xlDown).Select
 Range("B21").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Range("A21").Select
 Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("B40").Select
```

I would like to change the range which runs until B40000

[image: Sample file]

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: What about `Range("B2:B20").Copy Destination:=Range("B21:B40000")`

Comment: This code edited into Range("B2:B20").Copy
    Range("B21:B40000").PasteSpecial it is not working

Comment: *"is not working"* is a completely useless error description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the size of the destination is a multiple of the sources size to copy properly:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyRangeDown()
    Dim Source As Range
    Set Source = Range("B2:B20")

    Source.Copy
    Range("B21").Resize(RowSize:=Source.Rows.Count * CLng(40000 / Source.Rows.Count)).PasteSpecial
End Sub
```